# Is it possible to specify which apps use which network interfaces on MacOS?

Tags: networking, macos

I have a MacBook Pro that is connected by Ethernet to two separate networks, one connected to the internet, and the other connected to a completely isolated network which is used to communicate to in-house servers. I need one application, specifically ATEM Software Control (produced by Blackmagic) to use the in-house network and all other traffic to use the network connected to the internet. Is there a way to configure this?

Comment: What problem are you having with how things are working now? Reading between the lines, I suspect you may just need to fix your interface order to make sure your "connects to the Internet" Ethernet interface is ranked higher than your "isolated network that goes nowhere" Ethernet interface. System Preferences > Network > [Gear icon menu button at the bottom of the interface list ] > Set Service Order… > [drag your Internet-connected Ethernet interface above your isolated-LAN Ethernet interface].

Comment: @Spiff It is currently setup that way. The ATM Software control doesn't work when both networks are connected are the internet network is a higher priority.

Comment: Here is a similar thread discussed before, please check if it was helpful to you: [Making a program use a specific network interface](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59547/making-a-program-use-a-specific-network-interface)

Comment: @Sunny This does help, but if I understand it correctly, you have to manually set every ip address to route. Is it possible to route the entirety of an application's traffic?

Comment: Great question. Have you been able to solve this?